# JIRA: find all my logged work for last week

Tags: filter, jira

How would I create a JIRA filter that lists all of the issues on which I've
logged time?  I can then apply this to the activity stream.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have Script Runner installed, you can use the following query. It will show you the issues only where you have logged work in JIRA.

```
issueFunction in workLogged("after 2014/09/01 before 2015/01/30 by <USER_NAME>")
```

Where the dates can be set to the range of the week you want to query, and the USER_NAME can be your username.

[Script Runner Documentation](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-workLogged(worklogquery))

Comment: issueFunction does not seem to exist.

Comment: You need to have Script Runner installed (free, incredibly useful addon)

Comment: You can do this without script runner. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40930243/1015595.

Answer (score 38):

Use advance searching via JQL:

```
worklogAuthor = currentUser() 
                AND worklogDate >= "2016/12/01" 
                AND worklogDate <= "2016/12/31"
```

Comment: If you indent your code by four spaces it will be automatically formatted, which reads and looks better.

Comment: Does it find issues with workLog items created in these dates among other workLogs? Can it aggregate only workLogs only for these days?

Comment: I couldn't  find worklogAuthor field in documentation: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira063/advanced-searching-fields-reference-683542531.html

Comment: worklogAuthor and worklogDate are only available in JIRA 7+

Comment: Elaborating on this, you can use the same query but for your current week :)
`worklogAuthor = currentUser()  AND worklogDate >= startOfWeek() AND worklogDate <= endOfWeek()`

Answer (score 19):

Using JQL you can do something like this and you won't need to update the filter every week.

```
    worklogAuthor = currentUser() 
AND worklogDate >= startOfWeek(-1w) 
AND worklogDate < startOfWeek()
```

[Source for startOfWeek()](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA043/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-startOfWeek)

Comment: If I type in this query it shows me the green tick but somehow I cannot save the filter. Looks like I cannot execute the query :-(

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are your answer.  Search the marketplace for "Timesheets" if you are using the built in JIRA work logging.  Personally, I have had a lot of success with [JIRA Timesheet Reports and Gadgets](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jira-timesheet-plugin).

If you are still wanting a JQL plugin to give you back your results OR you are using JIRA cloud, have a look at [JQL Pro](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jql-pro), it appears to do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

What worklogs are you using? Sadly, it is not possible with the JQL. You might get lucky if you are using some plugins such as [Tempo](http://www.tempoplugin.com/) as they might have some internal reports.