# Get Jira worklogs from a period of time using jira rest api

Tags: rest, api, url, jira

I'm currently developing a program that get all the worklogs of a employee in the past month(using jira) and i can't make the url to get the worklogs from a period of time. Anyone knows how to do that ?

What i can do:
http://my-jira-domain/rest/api/latest/search?jql=assignee=name-employee&fields=worklog

And jira return all the worklogs of that assignee.

Thx, guys

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `worklogAuthor` query to filter work logs down by date:

```
https://my-jira-domain/rest/api/latest/search?jql=worklogAuthor = name-employee AND worklogDate >= "2018/1/01" AND worklogDate <= "2018/12/31"
```

Encoded, that URL would look like this:

```
https://my-jira-domain/rest/api/latest/search?jql=worklogAuthor%20%3D%20name-employee%20AND%20worklogDate%20%3E%3D%20%222018%2F1%2F01%22%20AND%20worklogDate%20%3C%3D%20%222018%2F12%2F31%22
```

Note that I tested this with JIRA 7.

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23159353/866021)